# calculate sum of multiples without merging common values

Tags: javascript

The following code results by combing common values into one:

```
//3,6,9,12,15------
//5,10,15----------

//result: sum of (3,5,6,9,10,12,15) = 60
```

---

```
int = 0;
for(var i=1;i<16;i++){
    if(i%3==0 || i%5==0){

        int +=i;
    }
}
alert(int);//60
```

---

But I wanted to get the output without combining:

```
    //3,6,9,12,15------|should ressult:
    //5,10,15----------|75

//result without combining: sum of (3,6,9,12,15,5,10,15) == 75
```

If you say I should do && instead of || then it will just result common sum i.e. 15 here in example.

So, how can I do?

Comment: Note, if you're working [Project Euler #1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1), your original solution (with multiples of 15 only counted once) will give you the expected result. There is also a pure arithmetic solution, and if you think about it a bit (or use Google), I'm sure you'll get an idea of how you could do this without a loop.

Comment: I googled a lot but couldn't find without loop. If you have idea please tell me. thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer for some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
int = 0;
for(var i=1;i<16;i++){
    if(i%3==0){
        int +=i;
    }
    if(i%5==0){
        int +=i;
    }
}
alert(int);//75
```

Or if you prefer a more compact solution:

```
int = 0;
for(var i=1;i<16;i++){
    int += (i % 3 ? 0 : i) + (i % 5 ? 0 : i);
}
alert(int);//75
```

Basically, for values that are multiples of 15, you count them twice.

---

*Hints regarding a solution without using a loop:* We can break the problem down to just list summing all the multiples of *n* between *a* and *b*-1. This can be computed directly without going through each number by taking a look at the sequence it produces. For *n*=3, *a*=1, *b*=28, this is:

> 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27

Notice now that 27+3=30, 24+6=30, 21+9=30, 18+12=30, and there's only one outlier in the middle, 15. So really all you need to know in order to solve this is the minimum element in the sequence, the maximum element, the number of elements, and the middle element if the the number of elements is odd. (In fact you don't even really need to know the middle number once you realize that it's precisely half of the sum the min and the max).

To help you out a bit more:

```
var max = Math.floor((b - 1) / n) * n;
var min = a + n - (a % n);
var count = (max - min) / n + 1;
```

Comment: @C-link Well, you could do `if(i%3==0 || i%5==0){ int += i; if(i%15==0){ int += i; } }`, but I'm not sure why that would be preferable to either of the solutions I've given here.

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand. As I wanted to know the sum as in the example without loop. Thank you very much for your effort.